# Is there a specific way to stop the test/simulation in case condition failure?

Tags: system-verilog, assert, uvm

I want the test to stop in the case of a failure condition.
I used `UVM_ERROR`, but this only produces a text message.
Is there a specific way to stop the test/simulation in case condition failure in addition to the text message (something like assert in systemVerilog)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `+UVM_MAX_QUIT_COUNT=1` runtime option on your simulator command line.  This will end the simulation after the 1st `UVM_ERROR`.